# XML creation in blackberry

Tags: xml, blackberry, java-me

I want to create an XML in blackberry as there are classes for that like Document and Element but i want the xml in String format is it any way to that .Is any API avialable in blackberry for doing the same

Answer (score 1):

There really aren't APIs for creating XML documents in the BlackBerry API.  You can sort of fake it by using net.rim.device.api.xml.jaxp.XMLWriter, and manually calling methods as if your program was a SAX parser, but that doesn't really buy you much.

Your best bet for structured XML writing is to use [KXML](http://kxml.sourceforge.net/), which is small and runs quickly on BlackBerry.  Specifically look at the org.kxml2.kdom package and the org.kxml2.io package (for the KXmlSerializer class).

Comment: I tried KXML but it does not recognizes the XML pullparser interface and not allowing me to compile any other option plz .

Comment: Yeah, KXML doesn't include that dependency - I can kind of understand why.  Anyway, you can get the pullparser interface from www.xmlpull.org (download the source zip, and just include the 4 files in the java/api folder in your project).

Comment: Hi ,
      I have created XML using KXML but i am facing the issue how to convert that xml to string format just like how transformerFactory works in java but which is not available in blackberry so how to proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise beginning with JSR-172.
If it is not available on blackBerry, Sun's reference implementation is pure java and probably open source as part of PhoneME.